# Using android phone as a DMZ/access point

Tags: wi-fi, networking, wifi-hotspot

I had a router suddenly die, and was wondering if I could use a spare Android phone as a temporary replacement.

Currently the network has one laptop connecting via Wi-Fi, and one desktop connecting via WiFi or ethernet.

The laptop and desktop should be able to talk to each other freely.

The internet connection for both came via the router, which was set up to extend another Wi-Fi network.

Does anything like this exist for Android?

I have a few spare phones lying around, including a Google Pixel and Essential Phone.